# Select DropDownList value using String from SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I can't get my code below to set my DropDownList to the correct value.

Its the code in the `else` statement that is not working for me but its not throwing any exceptions either.

The DropDownList is being set from one database where I store program information. The database I'm accessing with `reader1` is a user information database which has the string value selected on registration from the DropDownList, so I cant use the index. Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong?

I just want to retrieve my text string from the user database, populate the DropDownList from the program database, then have the database show the item that matches the string. Its this last part, auto selecting the item, thats the problem.

```
private DataTable loadAdBusinessTypes1()
        {
            string prgInfoConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["program_infoConnection"].ToString();
            SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(prgInfoConnection);
            SqlCommand oSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            oSqlCommand.Connection = oSqlConnection;
            oSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oSqlCommand.CommandText = "pGetAdBusinessTypes";
            SqlDataAdapter oSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            oSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = oSqlCommand;
            DataTable oDataTable1 = new DataTable("AdBusinessTypes");
            oSqlDataAdapter.Fill(oDataTable1);
            return oDataTable1;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["New"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx"); //*****CHANGE REDIRECT WEBPAGE*****
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    DataTable oDataTable = loadAdBusinessTypes1();
                    BusTypeddl.DataSource = oDataTable;
                    BusTypeddl.DataTextField = "business_type";
                    BusTypeddl.DataBind();
                }

                try
                {
                    if (Session["New"] == null)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx"); //*****CHANGE REDIRECT WEBPAGE*****
                    }
    else
                        {

                            string str = Convert.ToString(Session["New"]);
                            string cmdText = @"select account_no, first_name, last_name, email_1, email_2, business_street_1, business_street_2, business_street_3, business_city, business_state, business_postal_code, business_country, company_name, business_type, phone_1, phone_2, phonecode_1, phonecode_2, website, registration_date, screens_no, user_password from users where email_1 =@email";
                            string cpUsersConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cp_usersConnection"].ToString();
                            using (SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cpUsersConnection))
                            using (SqlCommand oSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, oSqlConnection))
                            {
                                oSqlConnection.Open();
                                oSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = str;
                                using (SqlDataReader reader1 = oSqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    if (reader1.Read())
                                    {

                                        var findBusType = reader1["business_type"].ToString().Trim();
                                        var selectedIndex = -1;

                                        for (int i = 0; i < BusTypeddl.Items.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                            if (BusTypeddl.Items[i].ToString() == findBusType)
                                            {
                                                selectedIndex = i;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (selectedIndex > -1)
                                        {
                                            BusTypeddl.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: `findBusType` columns contains a string and you need to search this string in `BusTypeddl`. If found then set it selected else default value will be selected? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it is. findBusType is just the variable Im using to alott the correct value to once it is found in the column by reader1.

Comment: It is ASP.NET so items are ListItems and a ListItem has the property Text, Try with _if (BusTypeddl.Items[i].Text.Trim() == findBusType)_

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your first method to:

```
private DataTable loadAdBusinessTypes1()
    {
        string prgInfoConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["program_infoConnection"].ToString();
        SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(prgInfoConnection);
        SqlCommand oSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("pGetAdBusinessTypes", oSqlConnection);
        oSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try{
            oSqlConnection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter oSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oSqlCommand);
            DataTable oDataTable1 = new DataTable("AdBusinessTypes");
            oSqlDataAdapter.Fill(oDataTable1);
            dt = oDataTable1;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            //you may work with exceptions here
        }
        finally{
            oSqlConnection.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Doesnt work either Im afraid. It executes but the ddl is still showing its default selection.

Comment: @DMur Add AutoPostBack property to your DropDownList control, populate OnSelectedIndexChanged on it and in your OnSelectedIndexChanged event method bind the value of your textbox